# Vectors divisible by 3 and 4

Tags: r

Im trying to make 2 empty vectors C and D and if vector (1:n) will be divisible by 3%%==0 then its need to be divide by a and be written into vector C same with D but 4%%==0 and then divide by b and writte to D vector

```
funkcia = function(a,b,n)
{
  vektor = 1:n
  C <- vector()
  D <- vector()
  for (i in 1:lenght(vektor)) {


    if(vektor[i]%%3==0)
      {
      y = vektor[i]/a
      C = c(C,y)
    }

    else if (vektor[i]%%4==0)
      {
      x = vektor[i]/b
      D = c(D,x)
    }
    print("vector C")
    print(C)
    print("vector D")
    print(D)
  }
}

funkcia(3,4,9)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this approach is close to what you originally intended:

```
funkcia = function(a,b,n)
{
  vektor = 1:n
  C <- vector()
  D <- vector()
  for (i in 1:length(vektor)) {
    if(vektor[i]%%a==0)
      {
      C = c(C,vektor[i])
      }
    if (vektor[i]%%b==0)
      {
      D = c(D,vektor[i])
    }
  }
    print("vector C")
    print(C)
    print("vector D")
    print(D)

}
```

```
funkcia(3,4,9)
[1] "vector C"
[1] 3 6 9
[1] "vector D"
[1] 4 8
```

Here's an alternative approach without any loops:

```
factor <- function(a, b, n) {
  init <- seq(1,n)
  result <- list(init[init %% a == 0],
                 init[init %% b == 0])
  names(result) <- c(paste0("div_",a),paste0("div_",b))
  result
}
factor(3,4,9)
$div_3
[1] 3 6 9

$div_4
[1] 4 8
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its working right

```
funkcia = function(a,b,n)
{
  vektor = 1:n
  C <- vector()
  D <- vector()
  for (i in 1:length(vektor)) {


    if(vektor[i]%%3==0)
      {
      y = vektor[i]/a
      C = c(C,y)
    }

    else if (vektor[i]%%4==0)
      {
      x = vektor[i]/b
      D = c(D,x)
    }

  }
  print("vector C")
  print(C)
  print("vector D")
  print(D)
}

funkcia(3,4,9)
```

Comment: i need to first check if number in vectors is divisible by 3 or 4 adn then divide it by a or b but yeah you right i changed in program now 3 and 4 in funnckua to other numbers